# Why do we believe certain things if they can’t be justified?

Tags: belief

Russell said that “there is no difference between sanity and insanity” if Hume’s problem of induction cannot be solved.

To me, I am not sure if I can justify that the sun will rise tomorrow, even probabilistically, because it has risen every day in the past. The problem of induction seems insurmountable.

Now, suppose you agree with this. Even if you don’t, suppose that you do. Now, if I still continue to believe that the sun will rise tomorrow (as presumably even Hume did), **why** is it that I believe in that in the first place if not for reason? If someone put a gun to my head, I would every single time assume that the sun will rise the next day rather than bet on it not. But if each belief is not justified, why do I, and many others who supposedly believe in the problem of induction, do this?

Is it an instinct? Is it just because it fits a pattern and assuming a certain pattern seems “better” than not? Is this even a philosophy question or a psychology one?

Comment: The problem of induction has been solve by (i) the acceptance we can only have uncertain knowledge and (ii) the acceptance that our knowledge is based both on theory (assumptions/consillience) as well as evidence (Kant).  Hume himself gives the solution that we apportion  our belief according to the evidence.

Comment: On what ground do you believe that your money will be tomorrow on your bank account? In fact, in some unlucky cases it will not.

Comment: You have "strong evidence" about the tomorrow rise of the sun, strong enough in order to avoid computing the probability of the event before going to sleep.

Comment: Because we are descendants of those who survived. Those who needed metaphysical justifications for the next sunrise did not. "*Which is not supported by any argument, or process of the understanding... must be induced by some other principle of equal weight and authority... It is an operation of the soul, when we are so situated, as unavoidable as to feel the passion of love, when we receive benefits; or hatred, when we meet with injuries,*" Hume.